# Implement do while in F#?

Tags: f#

I tried the following code to implement do while in F#.

```
let listObjects bucketName = asyncSeq {
    use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
    let request = new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 10)

    while (
        let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
        for entry in response.S3Objects do
            yield entry.Key
        response.IsTruncated) do ()
```

However, it cannot compile? Is the following code the only option?

```
let listObjects bucketName = asyncSeq {
    use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
    let request = new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 10)
    let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
    for entry in response.S3Objects do // do while
        yield entry.Key
    while response.IsTruncated do
        let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
        for entry in response.S3Objects do
            yield entry.Key
```

Comment: There is no do...while, there are some alternatives and reasons given in this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012533/why-do-while-does-not-exist-in-f - I like the `doWhile` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generally use tail-recursion in F# to solve the same sort of problems you'd solve with loops in C#.  I'm not entirely clear on what your intended while-loop behavior is, but here's an example of tail-recursivlely yielding the `S3Objects` until `response.IsTruncated` is false:

```
let listObjects bucketName = 
    asyncSeq {
        use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2)
        let request = new ListObjectsV2Request(BucketName = bucketName, MaxKeys = 10)
        let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let rec getKeys () = 
            asyncSeq {
                for entry in response.S3Objects do
                    yield entry.Key
                if response.IsTruncated
                then yield! getKeys ()
            }   

        yield! getKeys()            
    }
```

Comment: I've updated the question, the line `let! response = client.ListObjectsV2Async(request) |> Async.AwaitTask` needs to be moved in the inner `asyncSeq {...}` now. And the outer `asyncSeq {...}` can be removed.

Comment: Actually I think the outer asyncSeq is still necessary to contain the `use`. Otherwise `client` will be disposed as soon as the function returns and before the asyncSeq actually gets enumerated.